# C++ pointers declaration order output segmentation fault or bus error

Tags: c++, pointers, segmentation-fault, bus-error

This would be two questions in one

I have two pieces of codes, the only difference being the order between the declaration of  int* a; and int cpt = 0; on lines 6 and 7.

**Case 1:**

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    cout<<"begin"<<endl;
    int* a;
    int cpt = 0;
    cout<<"after init "<<a<<endl;
    *a = 2;
    cout<<"after assign"<<endl;
    cout<<a<<" "<<*a<<endl;
    cout<<"after cout"<<endl;
    int* b;
    *b = 2;
    cout<<b<<" "<<*b<<endl;
}
```

**Output:**

```
begin
after init 0x7fff6c97f05e
Bus error: 10
```

**Case 2:**

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    cout<<"begin"<<endl;
    int cpt = 0;
    int* a;
    cout<<"after init "<<a<<endl;
    *a = 2;
    cout<<"after assign"<<endl;
    cout<<a<<" "<<*a<<endl;
    cout<<"after cout"<<endl;
    int* b;
    *b = 2;
    cout<<b<<" "<<*b<<endl;
}
```

**Output:**

```
begin
after init 0x7fff50e4ac00
after assign
0x7fff50e4ac00 2
after cout
Segmentation fault: 11
```

I'm wondering why the declaration order affects the error. The cpt variable isn't used anywhere, so why would it's declaration affect the error?

I'm also wondering why does the pointer "a" in the second case doesn't produce a segfault when referencing it when the "b" pointer does produce a segfault. They have the same declaration and same usage, why the difference?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The key is what you're doing (dereferencing an uninitialized pointer) results in **undefined behavior,** so you really can't expect *anything* in particular to happen, nor is there a reasonable/"standard-conformant" explanation for what the program does. It can be, however, the case, that the stack is set up in a way that in the second case, `a` points to a valid memory location by accident, but that's just a guess.

Comment: And a guess is really all you can do here, it being undefined and all.

Comment: I agree with that, the problem is that the accident repeats itself over and over again when executing the same code. An accident that is constant like that seems to be standard no?
The "a" pointer is always initialized and doesn't produce a segfault while the "b" pointer always produce a segfault.

Comment: @Sam No, it's just your OS that reusing the same memory region/allocation pattern for your process...

Comment: @Sam, Usually, undefined behaviour is pretty consistent when not making any changes to the code and just running it again and again (on the same platform, of course). Not much has changed that would screw it up logically, but keep in mind that basing undefined behaviour on logic can never work. For the most part, it will probably usually be the same when just rerunning it, but there's always a very open possibility for doing something else.

Comment: @ H2C03 With different adresses?

Comment: @chris thanks for the advice! Would undefined behavior also explain the difference between the two cases?

Comment: @Sam, There's usually some plausible explanation for the behaviour, though with uninitialized pointers, it's a bit harder. It would make more "sense" with something like accessing an out-of-bounds element of an array and eating into a previously declared variable. While there might be an explanation for what could be happening behind the scenes, it's important to never assume that's what it *is* doing. It's undefined, and that comes foremost.

Comment: Thanks for the answers. Undefined = bad, got it.